# Removing last Sepcial Character in String using jQuery

Tags: jquery, split, substring, slice

I have a string it contains project name and project ID.

`var projectName= "BMW-ASSET-Management- 1133978889"`

**From above code i need to remove last - symbol.**

I need  `var projectName="BMW-ASSET-Management";  var projectId="1133978889";`

I tried to get projectId like
 `var projectId= projectName.slice(0,-13);`

But not working this.

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: _"I tried slice and substring but not working as expected"_... please [edit] your question to include your attempts and show what results you got

Comment: Also, do you actually have a space before the project ID?

Comment: Yes before project id there is a space like - 1234567891

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
x.split(/-\s/)
```

It will split into two parts as you expected

```
x = "BMW-ASSET-Management- 1133978889"
let [projectName, projectId] = x.split(/-\s/)
```